Why does RAG work?
Consider a corpus of answer sheets of History exam at high school level. Say it is 10 GiB in size.
Case 1
Assume that these answer sheets were part of much larger corpus used to train an LLM such as Llama, etc.
Case 2
Assume that the corpus of answer sheets resides in a vector database but not in the LLM.
Case 3
Assume that the corpus of answer sheets resides in a vector database and in the LLM too.
As an end user, I enter a prompt as follows.

You are a high-school teacher of History. Write a paragraph on impact of World War II on cinema.

In case 2 and 3, the vector database will be searched for documents closest to the user prompt and those documents will be used to enhance the prompt.

Given that the RAG approach alters the "question" (prompt) and does not alter "knowledge" (the LLM), how do we still get the "right" answer?
Will the output vary across all through scenarios?

Note, I am an above average programmer but not good with neural network and math.
See  https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/656/109 for code example.


Given that the RAG approach alters the "question" (prompt) and does not alter "knowledge" (the LLM), how do we still get the "right" answer?

Because the RAG uses a retriever to retrieve hopefully relevant docs from the  vector database. The relevant docs are given to the LLM via the prompt.

Will the output vary across all through scenarios?

Cases 2 and 3 should give about the same output, since answer sheets are just a small part of  the large corpus to train the LLM.
Case 1 may give a different output if the knowledge answer sheets aren't "well-known" and/or don't represent the "consensus" in the large corpus used to train the LLM.

So, in case of 2 and 3, the LLM serves only the purpose of responding as a human while using the knowledge from vector database. Is this right?

@cogitoergosum correct. In some cases, the LLM may still use some knowledge from its initial training set. That depends on how well the LLM follows the prompt (which typically says only look at the retrieved documents).
